# Azure Functions cost when developing locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I'm trying to identify a cost that is coming from my azure storage account hosting my azure functions. I've been developing locally mostly and use azure storage emulator and running the `func start` cmd. My questions is if this setup could still be contributing to my storage data transfer cost or it shouldn't cost a thing? I wouldn't think it would, but this is process of elimination for me.

Comment: No this doesn’t cost anything if it’s local development using the emulator

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no cost while running your functions and durable functions locally, by leveraging the Azure Compute and Storage emulators.